# What version of Outlook introduced "Quick Delete"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

In what version of Outlook did Microsoft introduce the quick delete button in the email list view. You see the delete button when you mouse over a message.
Did it exist in Outlook 2010? Its definitely in Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this feature was introduced in Outlook 2013 version.

> **Quick Actions in Message List**
>
> Flag, delete, or mark your messages read or unread with handy commands in the message list.

Reference: http://thesoftwarepro.com/outlook-2013-new-features/